# How to display Grid view inside the Item selector in EXTjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this sample item selector from `EXTjs`.[image]

I want to add a grid view something like this. ( I achieved this custom component using the field container, but it doesn't extend any properties that the Item selector provides)
[image]